# Google sign-in sends multiple requests on redirect

Tags: servlets, google-signin

I'm trying to implement Google sign-in on my web application, as an add-on to normal server-side authentication. The problem is,I'm not able to redirect the page to a Servlet to go to the user homepage. Instead, whenever I try to redirect ONCE,I get continuous requests to the next Servlet(I used print statements on the Servlet to check this).It seems as if the page reloads after every request sent to the Servlet. I also tried using form data to fix this, but that doesn't work either.

How do I stop this from happening? I'm a newbie, so any dumbing down will be much appreciated. In case this is a duplicate, please do send the link. I have tried to find a similar question, but have had no luck so far.

Note: I have removed all irrelevant lines of code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>

    <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id"
        content="CLIENT_ID_HERE">
    <script>
        function onSignIn(googleUser) {
            var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
            //document.cookie = "emailId=" + profile.getEmail();
            redirectPost(profile.getEmail());
            //window.location = "http://localhost:8080/auth/gmailhome";
        }
        function redirectPost(data) {
            var inputElement = document.getElementById('emailId');
            var form = document.getElementById("gmailLoginForm");
            inputElement.value = data;
            form.submit();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="gmaillogin" id="gmailLoginForm">
        <input type="hidden" id="emailId" name="emailId">
    </form>
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to solve this issue, and it just occurred to me that I can leave this here in case someone needs it in the future.

The problem we have is that onSignin() gets called as long as the user is signed in, and the status of the user doesn't reflect that they are signed in. I'm not sure why the state isn't changed automatically-perhaps there is some other purpose to this, or this is just low-priority right now.

So, what we do is add a listener that monitors whether or not the user is signed-in.

Something like this

```
function onLoad() {
    gapi.load('auth2', function () {
        gapi.auth2.init();
        gapi.auth2.isSignedIn.listen(function (isSignedIn) {
            this.setState({ status: isSignedIn })
            })
        })
    }
```